# Leaflet.Path.Transform - is there a way to add edge markers in the middle of each border?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I want to add circles in the middle of each border (only visually).
Is there a way to do it?

[image: the result I want]

There are `handlerOptions` but I couldn't find something like that there.

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet-Draw is not maintained anymore.
What you seek is easily possible in Leaflet-Geoman, which I want to encourage you to check out.

[image]

Check out the demo here: https://geoman.io/demo